# Can't add resource when defining a server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8

I'm attempting to define a server in the Eclipse (Oxygen) Server view. My project was not visible in the list of resources so per the following answer:

[Cannot add a project to a tomcat server in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380125/cannot-add-a-project-to-a-tomcat-server-in-eclipse)

I configured project facets as follows:

- Dynamic Web Module: 4.0
- Java: 1.8
- JavaScript 1.0

This made the the project visible when I tried again to define the server but I can't add it because "*Tomcat version 8.5 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, and Java EE 5, 6, and 7 Web modules*". This answer:

[Tomcat version 7.0 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, and Java EE 5 and 6 Web modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087833/tomcat-version-7-0-only-supports-j2ee-1-2-1-3-1-4-and-java-ee-5-and-6-web-mod)

makes some suggestions for Tomcat 6 and 7 but I can't get it working for 8 (also don't seem to be able to back out of the facet configuration, though I haven't tried deleting it in *.settings* yet).

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: The Dynamic Web facet versions match the Servlet spec, not the Java EE version, and Servlet 4.0 is in Java EE 8. Servlet spec 4 is only supported in Tomcat 9. http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: That worked, thanks. I had to delete the file in .settings and then I could set the Dynamic Web facet to 3.1.