# I facing issue in Apache Tomcat Server?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I working on Eclipse Project just I Changing jre 1.8 to 1.5 version and I run in tomcat server but its not running.changing many tomcat version.its not working.

How to find jre 1.5 version support which tomcat server.

I tried 3.2,4.0,5.0,5.5,6.0,7.0 but its not working.how to jre 1.5 supporting tomcat version use to run.can any give suggestion.-

Comment: According to the following link , it should work starting with Tomcat 6 : http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html . Do you have error messages ?

Comment: @Arnaud I tried but tomat server throwing this type of error  Tomcat version 6.0 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, and Java EE 5 Web modules.

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087833/tomcat-version-7-0-only-supports-j2ee-1-2-1-3-1-4-and-java-ee-5-and-6-web-mod

Comment: I guess you opened the Apache Tomcat server properties editor in Eclipse, clicked on `Runtime Environment` and changed the JRE. It's possible that there are still class path entries left pointing to the proviously selected JRE. Click on `Open launch configuration` (right below `Runtime Environment`) and switch to `Classpath` tab. If there's an entry referring to the wrong JRE remove it.

Comment: *Why* do you need a version of Tomcat that supports a long since end-of-lifed level of Java? As @Arnaud directed you to, Tomcat 6.x was the last version to not require a version of Java newer than 1.5. And what does “its not working” actually *mean*?